# Convert char* to wchar_t* using mbstowcs_s

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, char

I've tried convert a char* to wchar_t*, but I'm having some trouble using the mbstowcs and Visual Studio wants mbstowcs_s...

```
char *port; 
size_t size = strlen(port) + 1;  
wchar_t* portName = new wchar_t[size]; 
mbstowcs(portName, port, size);
```

How can I change the function to mbstowcs_s?

Comment: And what is the problem you're having? Have you checked the [MSDN reference on `mbstowcs_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eyktyxsx.aspx)?

Comment: What about disabling C4996 ?

Comment: Your application security will benefit far more from `std::string` and `std::wstring` than from `mbstowcs_s`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend disabling the secure code warnings when the fix to use the secure methods is so easy, so here you go:

```
    const char *port="8080";
    size_t size = strlen(port) + 1;  
    wchar_t* portName = new wchar_t[size]; 

    size_t outSize;
    mbstowcs_s(&outSize, portName, size, port, size-1);

    std::wcout << portName << std::endl;
```

Tested with `cl  /W3 /EHsc` on VS2013.

Comment: Be carefull though to not create a memory leak! delete the portName

Comment: What exactly size and size-1 does in the API?