# Update folder icon with desktop.ini & instantly change (C++)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, explorer, desktop.ini

After reading a lot and trying for 2 days in a row, I managed to make something work [by following this Microsoft tutorial on folder icons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-customize-folders-with-desktop-ini?redirectedfrom=MSDN), but it's not perfect - changes don't take place immediately. I need to restart explorer / reboot my computer or wait a couple of minutes (randomly) until I see the old icon change to the new icon.

## TL;DR

**Expected result:** I want to programmatically update my folder icon and see that the new icon take place instantly, without waiting. (using `c++`, `.bat`, `node.js` or anything else that would work, I don't mind really).

**Problem:** After chaining my `.ico` file, I expect to see the result immideiately, but I only see it after 30 seconds to 4 minutes or so. It changes instantly as well sometimes, but very rarely, and I want it to work 100% of the time.

**Requirements and notes:**

- It **must not** restart Explorer.
- It would be better if it would not clear the entire thumbnail cache from all folders and files, as it only needs to update a single folder icon.

## Hopes / unfulfilling attempts

### Renaming `desktop.ini` programmatically (Not working unfortunately)

I found a way to see the icon change immediately, [but it worked only when manually renaming desktop.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33309382/changing-desktop-ini-doesnt-update-folder-icon-automatically-in-windows) through the explorer itself. (changing desktop.ini to uppercase/lowercase or to desktop-temp.ini and then back to desktop.ini) When doing so, I see the folder icon change immediately.

That led me to a hope that I can do the same programmatically, so I tried this C++ code, that changes `desktop.ini` to `desktop-temp.ini` and back to `desktop.ini`, also with notifying windows that a change has occurred, but it did not work unfortunately.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winbase.h>
#include <Tchar.h>
#include <shlobj.h> // for SHGetSpecialFolderPathA


const char folderpath[] = "C:\\Users\\elron\\Elron Apps C\\005 Folder Icon\\paste-folder-icon";

int main()
{
    // rename("C:\\Users\\elron\\Elron Apps C\\005 Folder Icon\\paste-folder-icon\\desktop.ini", "desktop-temp.ini");

    if (MoveFile(_T("C:\\Users\\elron\\Elron Apps C\\005 Folder Icon\\paste-folder-icon\\desktop.ini"), _T("desktop-temp.ini")))
    {
        printf("succeeded\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error %d\n", GetLastError());
    }

    SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ALLEVENTS, SHCNF_NOTIFYRECURSIVE, NULL, NULL);
    SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ALLEVENTS, SHCNF_NOTIFYRECURSIVE, folderpath, NULL);

    if (MoveFile(_T("C:\\Users\\elron\\Elron Apps C\\005 Folder Icon\\paste-folder-icon\\desktop-temp.ini"), _T("desktop.ini")))
    {
        printf("succeeded\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error %d\n", GetLastError());
    }

    SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ALLEVENTS, SHCNF_NOTIFYRECURSIVE, NULL, NULL);
    SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ALLEVENTS, SHCNF_NOTIFYRECURSIVE, folderpath, NULL);
}
```

### `SHChangeNotify()` (works, but not immidiately)

Inspired by: [How to refresh the folder icon instantly in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45921769/how-to-refresh-the-folder-icon-instantly-in-windows)

I tried running this C++ code (after compiling using npm command `g++ -o refresh-folder-icons refresh-folder-icons.cpp`) and it worked! but I the changes take place between 1 to 5 minutes and if you're lucky, then you see it instantly. This is not reliable. I tested this on two computers (both Windows 10).

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <ShlObj.h>

const char folderPath[] = "path/to/folder";

int main()
{
    SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_UPDATEITEM, SHCNF_PATH, folderPath, NULL);
    SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ALLEVENTS, SHCNF_NOTIFYRECURSIVE, "path/to/folder/desktop.ini", NULL);
}
```

### "Use a shell function that will notify all running Explorer windows to use the updated desktop.ini" using VBScript (Did not work for me)

I've also tried creating a `.bat` file followed by this: [Changing desktop.ini doesn't update folder icon automatically in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33309382/changing-desktop-ini-doesnt-update-folder-icon-automatically-in-windows) but my folder still shows the previous icon.

### Refresh Icons Using IE4UINIT

[Following this](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/refresh-icon-cache-windows-7-quickly/)

Run the following command (for Windows 10) and hit Enter: `ie4uinit.exe -show`
For Windows 8 and earlier, run this command instead: `ie4uinit.exe -ClearIconCache`

### Refresh Icons Using [NirCmd](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)

[Following this tutorial (step 3)](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/refresh-icon-cache-windows-7-quickly/), I tried installing [NirCmd](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) and running all three, none of them refreshed my folder icon:

```
nircmd.exe sysrefresh 

nircmd.exe sysrefresh environment 

nircmd.exe sysrefresh policy
```

### [`SHGetSetFolderCustomSettings()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetsetfoldercustomsettings) (My main hope!!!)

[Someone wrote here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/745ef0ff-9659-4dea-8715-012f90836a9a/how-to-tell-file-explorer-to-update-when-a-desktop-ini-changes-using-shchangenotify?forum=windowssdk) that the `SHGetSetFolderCustomSettings` "function sets an icon and sends all necessary notification by itself", and that really have me hope that this is the right path.

Also, in Peter Tseng's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464147/how-can-i-immediately-reload-a-folder-icon-when-desktop-ini-is-changed) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945892/custom-folder-icons-with-desktop-ini-instant-refreshing) he shows a sample code that worked, but when I try to complie this C++ code into `.exe`, I get errors. This is the code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlobj.h>

int main()
{
    SHFOLDERCUSTOMSETTINGS pfcs;
    pfcs.dwMask = "C:\\Users\\elron\\Elron Apps C\\005 Folder Icon\\paste-folder-icon\\folderico-1629960936.ico";
    pfcs.pszIconFile = "C:\\Users\\elron\\Elron Apps C\\005 Folder Icon\\paste-folder-icon\\folderico-1629960936.ico";
    pfcs.cchIconFile = 0;
    pfcs.iIconIndex = 0;
    PCWSTR pszPath = L"C:\\Users\\elron\\Elron Apps C\\005 Folder Icon\\paste-folder-icon\\test\\hey";
    SHGetSetFolderCustomSettings(pfcs, pszPath, FCS_FORCEWRITE);
}
```

but I get three errors, all indicating to the same problem:

- `'SHFOLDERCUSTOMSETTINGS'` was not declared in this scope (gcc)
- `'pfcs'` was not declared in this scope (gcc)
- `'SHGetSetFolderCustomSettings'` was not declared in this scope (gcc)

**Why am I getting this error? Is there's a dependency I'm missing? I'm using windows 10.**

---

Comment: `ShlObj_core.h` -- Your `SHFOLDERCUSTOMSETTINGS` values are almost all wrong. - Shouldn't you set the size of the struct?

Comment: I'm new to C++, so I might have got it all wrong. What do you mean by the size of the struct? In lines 1359-1387 you can see the struct. https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/master/Include/10.0.10240.0/um/ShlObj.h#L1359

Comment: `DWORD dwSize` is set to the size of `SHFOLDERCUSTOMSETTINGS` (you'll find it quite often :) - `dwMask` (as `dw` implies ) is a `DWORD`: see what you set.

Comment: I see. Is that mandatory? Are all the values mandatory? I see `dwSize`, `dwMask`,`pvid`,`pszWebViewTemplate`,`cchWebViewTemplate`,`pszWebViewTemplateVersion` and many more. I don't know what to fill them.

Comment: SHChangeNotify is the way to go, but use Unicode paths and function (SHChangeNotifyW(SHCNE_UPDATEITEM, SHCNF_PATHW, ...), or if you have special characters it won't work), also use proper Windows path, with \ not / directory separators.

Comment: Check the Docs then: [SHFOLDERCUSTOMSETTINGS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/ns-shlobj_core-shfoldercustomsettings)

Comment: @Jimi How do I know the "The size of the structure, in bytes"?

Comment: `pfcs.dwSize = sizeof(SHFOLDERCUSTOMSETTINGS);`

Comment: Cool, I'll try that. But I still encounter this error: `'SHFOLDERCUSTOMSETTINGS' was not declared in this scope (gcc)` and it prevents me from compiling the file. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get working the last approach (using `SHGetSetFolderCustomSettings()`)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlobj.h>

int main()
{
    /*
    convert the icon's path to LPWSTR, as required by field pszIconFile
    method taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29847036/convert-char-to-wchar-t-using-mbstowcs-s
    */
    const char* iconPath = "C:\\Users\\YourUsername\\PathTo\\YourIcon\\file.ico";
    size_t size = strlen(iconPath) + 1;
    wchar_t* wtext = new wchar_t[size];

    size_t outSize;
    mbstowcs_s(&outSize, wtext, size, iconPath, size - 1);
    LPWSTR ptr = wtext;

    // (fixed the initialization of some fields)
    SHFOLDERCUSTOMSETTINGS pfcs{};
    pfcs.dwSize = sizeof(SHFOLDERCUSTOMSETTINGS);
    pfcs.dwMask = FCSM_ICONFILE;
    pfcs.pszIconFile = ptr;
    pfcs.cchIconFile = 0;
    pfcs.iIconIndex = 0;
    PCWSTR pszPath = L"C:\\Users\\YourUsername\\PathTo\\YourFolder\\FolderToCustomize";
    SHGetSetFolderCustomSettings(&pfcs, pszPath, FCS_FORCEWRITE);
}
```

I think the problems you mentioned:

> but I get three errors, all indicating to the same problem:
>
> - `'SHFOLDERCUSTOMSETTINGS'` was not declared in this scope (gcc)

might be caused because you weren't using the appropriate compiler. I got similar compile errors when using `g++` directly from the console/on Visual Studio Code, but the same code worked when using Visual Studio 2022 (Visual C++ compiler). I'm also new to C++, so feel free to correct me if this is not the source of the problem.

Comment: SHFOLDERCUSTOMSETTINGS requires at least Windows Vista as Target, if MinGW doesn't provide it for GCC, probably Windows XP was targeted.